# Percentage of a Percentage In excel piecharts?

Tags: excel, charts, pie-chart

Is there any possible way to show a percentage of another percentage in excel pie charts?

I have a pie chart[image: Pie Chart] that is supposed to show the amount of parts that have been completed and how many are remaining. on the side of that I am also tracking the amount of issues we are having with each part and I have a total number of all the issues as well. all I want to do is show the total completed and total remaining, and with in the total completed section have that show the percentage of issues with that total of parts.
I have attached an image of where I am at right now which includes every total and the percentage for issues/completed.

Comment: It would be helpful to see *all* the relevant data associated with the chart. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54221157/edit) to add it (ideally as text and not a screen cap)?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the percentage you want in the worksheet and dynamically place the result in a text box, as shown in the picture.

[Look this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRYur.png)

Then you can position and format the text box near the graphic as you wish.

I love this technique and I use it a lot.